# UISearchDisplayController - Method for when cancel button is clicked

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a UISearchDisplayController that shows the cancel button.  I would like to call a method when a user clicks the cancel button.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the following  searchbar delegate method,

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
     // DO ur operations
}
```

Comment: This is valuable, since iOS 7 seems to force the cancel-button for UISearchDisplayControllers.

Answer (score 1):

For UISearchDisplayController, the following 2 methods can be considered.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"WillEndSearch");
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller
{
    NSLog(@"DidEndSearch");
}
```